# How to get row index from multiple conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement, indexing

I have an array like this:

```
1.000000000000000000e+00    1.520566339739816631e-37
1.000000000000000000e+00    1.147965053727746877e-34
1.000000000000000000e+00    1.372739777414123007e-34
1.000000000000000000e+00    3.223982667840949347e-35
1.000000000000000000e+00    4.169420491209704059e-36
1.000000000000000000e+00    1.548157233879109404e-37
1.000000000000000000e+00    1.201472854896589573e-37
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00    0.000000000000000000e+00
```

I want to get the row index with conditions like these:

1. The first condition is where the value of the first column = 1 and the value of the second column = 0. Which is started from the 8th column.
2. The second condition is if the first condition repeats for more than 5 times, then it prints out the first row index, which is 8 (or in Python is the 7th row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st filter all the index by first criteria and then go for second criteria.

**arr:**

```
array([[1. , 1.5],
       [1. , 1.1],
       [1. , 1.3],
       [1. , 3.2],
       [1. , 4.1],
       [1. , 1.5],
       [1. , 1.2],
       [1. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0. ]])
```

Try:

```
idx = np.min(np.where((arr[:,0]==1) & (arr[:,1] == 0)))
count = Counter(l for l in arr[idx:,0])
if count[1] > 5:
    print(idx)
```

---

**Output:**

```
7
```

Comment: l is your 1st column starting from the index where your first criteria matches that is 7th index